# Netbeans problems with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, netbeans, rcp

Why Netbeans takes so much time in **java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(String)**?

I have isolated my problem and I have two projects:

I created a **Netbeans Platform program** with one module that has one window and one button in it. So when I click it, program runs the function that I need.

I created a **form** that will call that function.

So now I have two programs that are the same and run from an AWT thread. The key difference is that one runs under Netbeans Platform structure and the other one is alone.
Profiling the two programs I found that the big problem is when it calls "java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(String)" **Netbeans program takes 30,784 ms and Swing program takes 2,055 ms**
It seems to me that Netbeans has some sort of security that checks when somebody is trying to access a class through reflection.
Does anybody knows what is it? and how to turn it off??

Thanks
HS

Comment: you can always dive in

Comment: Possibly netbeans is using a different JRE.

Comment: You should probably mention which version of NetBeans you're using.  That said, every version of NetBeans seems to do lots of unnecessary things that slow everything down all the time...

Comment: Netbeans 7.3, JDK 1.7.0_21, 64 bits. Windows 7 Ultimate. I am going to try play around java options.